# Select all siblings between two nodes excluding them

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have to select all the content between the h1 nodes.

```
<html>
<h1>Index</h1>
<p>some content</p>
<p>some more content</p>
<h1>Index 2</h1>
<p>some content</p>
<h2>other content</h2>
<h1>Index 3</h1>
<p>some  content</p>
<p>other content</p>
<h1>Index 4</h1>
<h2>some content</h2>
<p>other content</p>
</html>
```

Which should result in something like this:

```
<heading>
  <p>some content</p>
  <p>some more content</p>
<heading>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 this is a nice case for `group-starting-with`:

```
<xsl:template match="html">
  <root>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
      <heading text="{.}">
        <xsl:sequence select="current-group() except ."/>
      </heading>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

`current-group()` is the whole group of elements from one h1 (inclusive) to the next (exclusive), and `.` is the first node in the group in document order (the h1), so `current-group() except .` gives you the nodes you want.

You may prefer to use `select="node()"` instead of `select="*"` if there may be text between the h1 elements that is not itself wrapped in another element, e.g.

```
<h1>Example</h1>
Some unwrapped text
<p>...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/html">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="h1" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h1">
      <heading>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::h1[1] = current()][not(self::h1)]"/>
      </heading>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that the predicate `preceding-sibling::h1[1] = current()` is comparing the _value_ of these two nodes, not their identities - if you had two h1 elements containing the same text then you'd get both their "groups" of content appearing under the same `heading`. To check for the _same node_ rather than the same value you should use the `is` operator in XSLT 2.0 (`preceding-sibling::h1[1] is current()`) or compare their `generate-id` values in 1.0 (`generate-id(preceding-sibling::h1[1]) = generate-id(current())`)